# Call c++ code in c# by a cli wrapper

Tags: c++-cli

I have a c++ code that needs to be called in c# by a cli wrapper. I am stuck at the operator overloading part.

//this is my code
//Cppclass.h

```
#ifdef CPP_EXP_EXPORTS
#define CPP_EXP __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define CPP_EXP __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

 class CPP_EXP Cppclass;
 CPP_EXP Cppclass  operator-(Cppclass const &, Cppclass const &);
 class CPP_EXP Cppclass
 {
 public:
 friend CPP_EXP Cppclass operator-(Cppclass const &, Cppclass const &);
 };
```

//this is my managed c++ code.

```
#include "Cppclass.h"

   namespace Wrapper
 {

    public ref class cppwrapclass
    {
      public:
       static cppwrapclass ^ operator-(cppwrapclass%A,cppwrapclass%B)
         {
            operator-(A.obj,B.obj);
            return gcnew cppwrapclass();
         }
      private:
        Cppclass *obj;
    };
 }
```

Its showing an intellisense error and not getting compiled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You write a wrapper like this:

```
public ref class cppwrapclass
{
public:
    cppwrapclass(Cppclass *obj)
        : obj(obj)
    {
    }

    ~cppwrapclass()
    {
        this->!cppwrapclass();
    }

    !cppwrapclass()
    {
        if (obj)
        {
            delete obj;
            obj = nullptr;
        }
    }

    static cppwrapclass^ operator-(cppwrapclass% A, cppwrapclass% B)
    {
        return gcnew cppwrapclass(new Cppclass(*A.obj - *B.obj));
    }

private:
    Cppclass* obj;
};
```

`A.obj` is of type `Cppclass*`, therefore `*A.obj` is of type `Cppclass`, and `*A.obj - *B.obj` is a temporary `Cppclass` which needs to be moved to the heap in order to be referenced by the wrapper, hence the copy constructor call: `new Cppclass(*A.obj - *B.obj)`.

The rest is the `Dispose` pattern and finalizer plumbing code.